# Pass String between custom Dialog Box and EditText

Tags: android, string, dialog

I'm using activity. When I clik on my EditText, a Dialog Box appear like this : 
http://techblogon.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/alert-dialog-with-edittext-in-android.png

How to pass String (my Name) now from Dialog Box to the EditText in my first activity please ? This is my code :

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

EditText inputName;
Button btnName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_name);

    inputName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Dialog();
        }
    });

    // Add Healthcare Button Click event
    btnName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final String nameD = inputDoctorName.getText().toString();
            Log.d("TEST","SUCCESS");
        }
    });



}

protected void Dialog()
{
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialogbox);
dialog.setTitle("Description de la note");
Button ok = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
dialog.dismiss();

}
});
dialog.show();

}
}
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `SharedPreference` to store the string and call it in your first `Activity`

Call this in your `Activity` with the `Dialog`

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
// Set up our Prefs and Editor
prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("YOURCHOICESTRING", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = prefs.edit();

//onClick (after the dialog closes and you goto your first Activity)
editor.putString("STRING VARIABLE", "THE STRING YOU WANT TO SAVE");
```

Use the following codes in your first `Activity` you want to display the string you saved from the `Dialog`:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
String strImageNum = prefs.getString("STRING VARIABLE", "");
// use strImageNum as you please.
```

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how you can use it. Of course you have to customize it to fit your need. Good luck!